# Объясните, пожалуйста, почему функция выводит не то, что по идее должна выводить

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, define

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, когда я пишу

```
def updatenumber(n):
     n *= 2
b = 8
updatenumber(b)
print(b)
```

выводится `8`, а не `16`. Ведь я задал функцию, которая должна умножить заданное число на `2`. Разве не должно быть так:

1. создана функция, умножающая число на `2`.
2. задается число `b = 8`.
3. Впихиваем в аргумент функции число `b`.
4. Создана новая переменная, значение которой равно `16`.

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переменная `n` существует только внутри функции `updatenumber` после завершения функции `n` исчезает

можете добавить `return` чтобы `b` был равен `16`

```
def updatenumber(n):
     n *= 2
     return n
b = 8
b = updatenumber(b)
print(b)
```

Comment: А как тогда создать функцию, которая будет, например, умножать заданное число на 2. То есть я хочу создать такую функцию, а потом уже просто вызывать ее, и, чтобы она выполняла то, что написано в ее теле. Как это сделать?

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.